# Android studio different layout on emulator

Tags: android, xml, layout

I just started using android studio and I inserted a button and text field. In preview panel looks ok but when I run the app the layout it's different.
This is the xml code:

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="16dp"
android:paddingTop="16dp"
android:paddingLeft="16dp"
android:paddingRight="16dp"

tools:context="com.example.alexander.myapplication.MainActivity">


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/message"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="TextView"
    tools:ignore="HardcodedText" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Button"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="119dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="222dp"
    tools:ignore="HardcodedText,MissingConstraints"
    android:onClick="buttonClicked"
    />
```

[This is how it looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BvUb3.png)
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Look at the lines:

```
tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="119dp"
tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="222dp"
```

What they say is that you placed the button in an absolute position BUT only in the editor preview.
The button doesn't have real placement values when the app actually running (notice the "editor" prefix in the parameters name).

You need to define actual values in the editor.

Check out this guide on the Android developers site: 
[Build a Responsive UI with ConstraintLayout](https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout/index.html)

Answer (score 0):

I just solved the problem by setting the layout to RelativeLayout.